# setValue for multiple formGroups

Tags: angular

Using model driven forms how can I setValue for a nested formGroup?  Without the nested formGroup I can do this as follows:

```
export class MyComponent {

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
      this.form = formBuilder.group({
        id: [],
        title: ['', Validators.required],
        start_date: ['', Validators.required],
        end_date: ['', Validators.required]
     });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    ...
    this.form.setValue({
      id: this.academicTerm.id,
      title: this.academicTerm.title,
      start_date: this.academicTerm.start_date,
      end_date: this.academicTerm.end_date
    });
    ...
  }

}
```

This works fine but if I nest the start and end dates into their own `dates` formGroup (for validation ... not shown) then I cannot find a way to set the start and end date values.

```
export class MyComponent {

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
      this.form = formBuilder.group({
        id: [],
        title: ['', Validators.required],
        dates: formBuilder.group({
          start_date: ['', Validators.required],
          end_date: ['', Validators.required]
        })
     });
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the date value as follow :

```
this.form.controls['dates'].setValue({
    start_date: '',
    end_date: '',
});
```

or the whole form :

```
this.form.setValue({
  id: '',
  title: '',
  dates: {
      start_date: '',
      end_date: ''
  }
});
```

But if you're doing it to set default values just do it when you are building the form instead of using empty values (`''`).